# Aligning a div element with content vertically centered irrespective of the resolution

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, html, c#-4.0

I have an application in which i'm troubling with the div elements.

I have div with the content, which contains many div's,span and some img tags.

I need to vertically center the content of the div element irrespective of the screen resolution and the browser.

I've tried like this:

```
<div style="padding-top: 4%;position:fixed;height:2%;>
my content
</div>
```

This works perfectly in all my browsers(FF,IE,CHROME,SAFARI).

However, this is not working in my friend pc, whose monitor is not a wide screen monitor.

please suggest me ideal css to work with any kind of resolutions.

EDIT:`my content` contains divs some are aligned horizontally and some of them are next to each other.

Thanks,

Comment: Dont you know exact height of your div? in pix?

Comment: If i set the height in pixels for div, it works for me but not for those whose monitor is like square i mean not a widescreen monitor

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div style="margin:auto;">
    my content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the division height in pixels, and add this :

```
div
{
    height:100px; // your height
    width:100px; 
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px; // half of your height
    position:fixed;
}
```

No need for padding or anything else.